# In Xcode, I want to update the title of a UIButton every time it is hit. Have it display 1 the first hit, 2 the second. You get it

Tags: xcode

I want to update the TITLE of a UIButton every time it is hit using a variable.

Comment: try googling first or atleast try it yourself then if you run into a problem that's the time you will ask. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this may cover what you're after [iPhone Tap Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895774/iphone-tap-counter)

where anotherLabel would be the name of your UIButton

```
static int count;
count++;
NSString *countString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count];
[anotherLabel setText: countString];
```